# Iterate thru some function with settimeout doesn't work as I expected

Tags: javascript

I was playing with javascript and tried to iterate thru some colors that were defined in an array just to make sure that I typed the color name correctly.  I used the following code:

```
<body onload="show_colors()">
  <script>
     var colors = ["blue", "cyan", "bisque", "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "aqua", "yellow", "azure", "cadetblue", "plum"].sort();
    var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

   function show_colors() {
     for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
         setTimeout(setBackgroundColor(colors[i]), 2000)
     }
   }

  function setBackgroundColor(color) {
    console.log('setting color to ' + color);
    myBody.style.background=color;
  }

</script>
```

I was surprised that the page loaded up pretty quickly, and just show "yellow" in the background.  I thought asked to have a 2 seconds delay using the setTimeout.  If I looked thru the console, I see the messages about the colors being set; but they weren't in a 2 seconds delay.  Did I misunderstand how settimeout() work or is this have something to do with my using the onload event?

Comment: `element.style.background` is not the attribute. Perhaps you're looking for `element.style.backgroundColor` ?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson, `background` is a valid property of an element's `style` property. It references the CSS background style

Comment: @PatrickEvans it seemed from his code that he was looking to change the color of his background.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson, he is, but `background` encompasses the other backgroud-* styles, so you can either put your various background styles in there or directly set one of the background-* styles either will work

Comment: @PatrickEvans - any references you can provide that would indicate it should be used like that?

Comment: [MDN CSS reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background). The caveat to using `background` is that it will overwrite the other background-* styles after being set. But since OP does not appear to be using any other styles it is a valid option.

Answer (score 2):

Set timeout requires a function reference. You're simply immediately invoking the function. Wrap it in an anonymous function like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        setBackgroundColor(colors[i])
    }, 2000)
}
```

Also, because I love it - you can shorten your show_colors method using ES6 lambda syntax.

```
function show_colors() {
    colors.forEach(color => setTimeout(() => setBackgroundColor(color), 2000));
}
```

Comment: Or you could just use the `bind()` method - `setTimeout(setBackgroundColor.bind(this, colors[i]), 2000*i)`

Comment: Though I do think ES6 syntax is prettier @SterlingArcher

Comment: You will have a problem with the first code, as `i` inside the callback will end up being the last value in the loop

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.

1. pass `setTimeout` a function to execute, as already mentioned.
2. The function needs to display the next color and not use the last value of a loop counter. One way of doing this is to hold the color in function scope.
3. Setting up all the timer calls needs to space the colors apart. At the moment they all execute after two seconds. You'll probably only see the last color.

E.G.

```
<script>
var colors = ["blue", "cyan", "bisque", "gray", "green", "magenta", "orange", "red", "aqua", "yellow", "azure", "cadetblue", "plum"].sort();

function toSetBackground(color) { // 1. return value is a function
    return function() {           // 2. color to use is in function scope
        console.log('setting color to ' + color);
        document.body.style.background = color;
    };
}


function show_colors() {
    for (var i=0; i<colors.  length; i++) {
        setTimeout(toSetBackground(colors[i]), 2000 * i); // 3. space the callbacks
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", show_colors);
</script>
```